# Create a manhattan plot in r

Tags: r, manhattan

This is my code thus far, but it keeps saying "...' used in an incorrect context? Any suggestions?

```
library(qqman)
manhattan(
pvalues_file,
chr = "CHR",
bp = "BP",
p = "P",
snp = "SNP",
col = c("gray10", "gray60"),
chrlabs = NULL,
suggestiveline = -log10(1e-05),
genomewideline = -log10(5e-08),
highlight = NULL,
logp = TRUE,
annotatePval = NULL,
annotateTop = TRUE,
...
)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to type `...`. `...` in the function definition just means that there are other arguments that you can chuck in there. If you don't want to, don't.

Comment: I assume the error message is different. What is it this time?